# Update column by join two tables using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I need to update the table column with the join with other table
My pseudocode for SQL is as follows:

```
 update table1 T1 set T1.user = T2.product where T2.product like '%P12%' 
 and T1.order = T2.order;
```

I have also tried using JOIN query but it is giving error "SQL command not properly ended" using Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In oracle, Update using `JOIN` is not allowed.

You can use `MERGE`. It can update one table using another table (s).

```
MERGE INTO T1
USING (SELECT T2.PRODUCT,
              T2.ORDER
         FROM T2 WHERE T2.PRODUCT LIKE '%P12%') T2 
ON ( T1.ORDER = T2.ORDER )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET T1.USER = T2.PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update table1 t1
set t1.user = (select t2.product from table2 t2 where t1.order = t2.order and t2.product like '%P12%' )
where exists(select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.order = t2.order and t2.product like '%P12%')
```

I find it quite surprising that one would update something called `user` from something called `product` - but this sticks to your original pseudo-code.

Comment: I need to edit my pseudo code little it is where T2.product like '%P12%'  , but when I use the same in the above where clause it is giving T2.product is invalid identifier.

Comment: @user2907032: that needs to go in the subqueries. I edited my answer.